overtly hostile comments from one person
Several days ago I attempted to answer this question:
How can we model the primordial Universe while the interior of a neutron star and comparable states of matter are still mostly unknown?
However, my posted answer has earned a flurry of increasingly disrespectful and hostile comments from one reader here. I want him to quit the insulting behavior and leave me alone. How can this be done?

You can flag the comments that you think are disrespectful. The moderators will review the flagged comments and can sanction the commenter if they agree (e.g., by disabling the offending account for a cool-off period).

I flagged one of the comments for you. They don't seem super disrespectful to me, but I'm kind of bordering on disrespectful myself some of the time... That being said, any comment that focusses on you rather than your answer is likely inappropriate and the mods will probably remove it and warn the commenter.

I see how to flag a question but not how to flag a comment. can you explain? thanks, Niels

The flag for the comment is to the left of the comment. There's a little up-arrow icon to the left and below that a little flag icon

@hft, thanks for your help, I appreciate it. this sort of thing has only happened twice in my 10 years here.

Just flag hostile comments and move on. Depending on the nature of a comment, choose "it contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse", "unfriendly or unkind", or a custom message if the two previous ones don't fit for some reason and move on. There is no need to engage with a person who harasses you with insults.
Best motto to live by: don't waste your time and effort, just flag the asshole and move on.

Thanks for your advice, I will try to follow it. -NN




Seconding the advice to flag it and move on ("fiamo," if you feel like announcing your decision to yourself with a pseudo-Italian flourish).

Thanks @rob, that raises my spirits. another SE guy counseled me by saying that life is a drunkard's walk through reputation space...
